# my credential authentication using next-auth wont work

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

so I am practicing on creating a login/signup form using nextjs with proper authentication and so on. My signin/registration works and enters the database, but the problem I am dealing right now is how to login since it says in

vscode terminal:

```
[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] 
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
```

browser console:

```
signInForm.tsx:15 
 
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/[...nextauth] 400 (Bad Request)
handleSubmit    @   signInForm.tsx:15
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:19462
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl   @   react-dom.development.js:19511
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:19586
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:19600
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:30652
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:30684
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:30697
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:30708
eval    @   react-dom.development.js:30898
batchedUpdates$1    @   react-dom.development.js:23767
batchedUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js:27614
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:30897
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:28670
dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

```
Login failed
window.console.error @ app-index.js:31
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:45
handleSubmit @ signInForm.tsx:27
await in handleSubmit (async)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19462
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ react-dom.development.js:19511
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19586
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:19600
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:30652
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:30684
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:30697
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:30708
eval @ react-dom.development.js:30898
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23767
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:27614
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:30897
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:28670
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:28641
```

this is my code for my [...nextauth]/route.ts api

```
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

my auth.ts file in library

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import prisma from "./prisma";
import { compare } from "bcrypt";


export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
            name: "Credentials",
            // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "jsmith" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
                    return null;
                }

                const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: { email: credentials?.email }
                });

                if (!existingUser) {
                    return null;
                }

                const passwordMatch = await compare(credentials.password, existingUser.password);

                if (!passwordMatch) {
                    return null;
                }

                return {
                    id: `${existingUser.id}`,
                    username: existingUser.username,
                    email: existingUser.email,
                };
            }

        })
    ]
};
```

then my (auth)/signin/page.tsx page

```
import SignInForm from '@/app/components/form/signInForm'
import React from 'react'

const signin = () => {
  return (
    <SignInForm />
  )
}

export default signin
```

lastly, my very simple SignInForm.tsx component

```
"use client"

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function SignInForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();

  const onSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/auth/[...nextauth]', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Login successful!');
        router.push('/profile');
      } else {
        console.error('Login failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I even tried to add nextauth url in my env variables according to copilot's suggestion

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error?  It tells you exactly how to fix the error.

Comment: ah yes an update, I actually did and I also added the secrets in my env variables so the "[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] " is gone now.

now I'm stuck with 400 (Bad Request) and I assume it has something to do with my backend api or maybe wrong referencing in my component